# Participle clause x main clause agreement

Tags: перевод, participle-clause, adverbial-participle

This is again from the B2 exam that I am trying to prepare for. The question is:
Всесторонне обсудив тему...
А) работа была начата
Б) было произведено начало работ
В) можно начинать работу
Г) работа началась

Why is В) the right answer? Would A) be correct if it was работа было начата? And would Г be correct if it was работа началось? Very confused about this one

Comment: also dealt with in [Is “глядя на нас, сразу понятно, что …” grammatically valid?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/1443/is-глядя-на-нас-сразу-понятно-что-grammatically-valid)

Answer (score 6):

This question tests your ability to use adverbial participles (*деепричастия*). They should be in agreement and not to be what English grammarians call "dangling participles".

According to the most strict points of view, all the answers above are incorrect: the adverbial participle requires a subject, a verb, and the subject being the agent for both the verb and the participle in the sentence.

The adverbial clause here reads "having thoroughly discussed the topic", so there has to be a subject and the subject should be the agent (something which did the discussion). In *А* and *Г* the subject is *работа* ("work"), and it did not do the discussion, so those are incorrect. In *Б*, the subject is *начало*, and it's not an agent for the participle either (the beginning or work did not do the discussion). Finally, in *В*, there is no subject at all.

However, the requirement for the existence of the subject can be relaxed. One of the most influential Russian style guides, *Справочник по правописанию, произношению, литературному редактированию* by Rosenthal et al., suggests:

> В ряде случаев возможно употребление деепричастного оборота, не выражающего действия подлежащего:
>
> 1) если производитель действия, обозначенного деепричастием, совпадает с производителем действия, обозначенного другой глагольной формой (инфинитивом, причастием, деепричастием), например: *Автору было предложено внести в рукопись дополнения, учитывая изменения, происшедшие в жизни общества за последнее время; Ничем нельзя было удержать напора волн, нахлынувших на берег, сметая все на своем пути;*
>
> 2) в безличном предложении при инфинитиве, например: *Приходилось работать в трудных условиях, не имея в течение многих недель ни одного свободного дня для отдыха.* Если же в безличном предложении нет инфинитива, к которому мог бы относиться деепричастный оборот, то употребление последнего стилистически неоправданно, например: *Уезжая из родного города, мне стало грустно; Прочитав вторично рукопись, редактору показалось, что она нуждается в серьезной доработке.*

*В* makes an impersonal sentence with an infinitive, so the usage of *В* is correct, at least, according to Rosenthal.

Comment: the subject of Б is начало

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка you're right, thanks!

Comment: But Б) fits into the first Rosenthal's case, doesn't it?

Comment: @Joker_vD no, it does not. The first case still requires a common agent (*автору, волн*), but allows it not to be the subject.

Comment: "Всесторонне обсудив тему, [нами] было произведено начало работ" — the agent is *мы* in both cases or am I just trying to guess too much in this sentence?

Comment: no, in Всесторонне обсудив тему, [нами] было произведено начало работ, нами is not a subject to agree with the participle clause, because it's not in Nominative, it's an object in Instrumental, such sentence implies that the discussion was conducted by начало, which is the subject of the main clause, and therefore is nonsensical

Answer (score 3):

In Russian subject of [participle clauses](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/intermediate-grammar/participle-clauses) must agree with the subject of the main clause. But it's also simply logical and should be true for other languages as well, English in particular.

> <sup>*correct*</sup> Выпив чаю, я отправился на работу  - Having drunk my tea I left for work
>
> <sup>*INcorrect*</sup> Выпив чаю, мне позвонили с работы  - Having drunk my tea a call from work came in

And only variant B adheres to this rule. The rest have different subject.

In the given participle clause the subject is humans (because only humans are endowed with ability to discuss things), in the variants A, Б & Г on the other hand it's either работа (А, Г) or начало (Б). Variant B just like the participle clause implies humans because they're those who able to commence work.

The question is admittedly difficult because variant B makes for an impersonal sentence where the subject isn't immediately evident.

Comment: я снова поправил заголовок - я отдаю себе отчёт, что он не идеальный, но вместе с тем хочу объяснить - по заголовку хотя бы приблизительно нужно понять о чём в вопросе речь - а заголовок навроде "Почему мой ответ неправильный" - эту задачу не решает совсем.

Comment: the OP doesn't ask anything specific about the variant Б plus the correct answer is B, so why has this title been preferred? it is misleading